# How to disable screen edge obstruction in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, settings, kde4, usability

Whenever I enable any action in `KDE -> System Settings -> Workspace behaviour -> Screen Edges` selected screen edge becomes unreachable by the pointer which is bounces against it. I don't want to apply additional pressure to activate the screen edge. How do I disable this misfeature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the activation delay to 0:

[image: Screen Edges – KDE Control Module]

Comment: It was 0 ms from the start, but decreasing Reactivation Delay made it more comfortable, thanks :) The screen corner is still unreachable.