# Where is the sticky edges option (for multiple screens)?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, 17.04

Online I find that there **used** to be a sticky edges toggle in the Displays settings window, but I  can't [find it there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kPu4.png).

Was the feature dropped? Was the toggle moved?

As the tag says: I'm on Kubuntu, not vanilla Ubuntu.

Comment: I think it may not exist in KDE, only Unity.

Comment: In Ubuntu this is handled with the Compiz Plugin called the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"  Maybe try installing compizconfig-settings-manager,  and running it to see if there is a similar Kubuntu plugin that gives you the option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this can help (I am not a Kubuntu user), but have you tried in `System Settings > Workspace Behaviour > Screen Edges`?
In older versions of Kubuntu, Sticky Edges were there...

Hope there are still there and solves your problem!

Comment: This is what that screen looks like today: http://i.imgur.com/BMPy7iW.png

Comment: There, you can set the "stickyness" of the screen edges: select what edges you want to use for changing from one screen to another, and play with the activation/reactivation relay for getting different "stick forces" in those edges... Maybe this thread helps you: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133210/how-to-disable-screen-edge-obstruction-in-kde)

Comment: Sticky Edges is the feature where you have to push harder to move the cursor between screens (monitors, displays) so it doesn't cross screens by mistake - not desktops (virtual desktops). http://i.imgur.com/k8iyjeg.png this binds actions to the edges.

Comment: You're right :) Well, then I think that that feature is not available in KDE...

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu18.04, I've found it in `System Settings > Dispalys`: there's a toggle `Sticky edges`