# sticky edges option on Kubuntu (for dual screen)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

It has been asked almost 4 years ago in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940496/where-is-the-sticky-edges-option-for-multiple-screens) question, and no one found a solution.
does anyone knows if this option is still missing? perhaps a kwin script could do the trick?

I think it shouldn't be difficult to implement, Unity already has it by many years, and so do Windows...

Comment: I am on Kubuntu 20.04 and it has sticky edges in the stock configuration.

Comment: @totalynotanoob can you please tell me the location of this setting? I searched everywhere but I can't find it... I'm on Kubuntu 21.04

Comment: Settings>Window Management>Movement (4th Tab)

Comment: that's about window sticky borders, but I was talking about screen sticky edges (that's the name in unity desktop settings), but thank you anyway! I'll edit the question to make it more understendable